# Product of integer polynomials has coefficients $0,\pm 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Do there always exist for any $n$ two polynomials $P(x),Q(x)$ with integer coefficients such that both $P(x),Q(x)$ have some term with coefficient greater than $n$ in absolute value, but the product $P(x)Q(x)$ has only coefficients $0,\pm 1$? It's possible that the coefficients cancel each other to leave only small coefficients, but it looks unlikely.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Do you mean something like $P(x)=x^2+2x+1$ and $Q(x)=x-1$ so that $P(x)Q(x)=x^3+x^2-x-1$?  Or, does this not count because $Q(x)$ doesn't have a term that is not $0,\pm1$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr That doesn't count for the reason you mentioned.

Comment: This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial#Integers_appearing_as_coefficients

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix an integer $n$, and let $p,q$ be two distinct primes greater than $2n$.

Suppose $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}a_kx^{kp}$ is a polynomial in $x^p$, and $g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}b_kx^{kq}$ is a polynomial in $x^q$, where all $a_k,b_k$ are integers. Then each non-zero term of the product $f(x)g(x)$ is of the form $a_ib_jx^{ip+jq}$ for some $i,j$, that is, it is the product of a unique pair of terms $a_ix^{ip}$ and $b_jx^{jq}$.

This tells us two things:

1. If either $f$ or $g$ has coefficients $\ge n$ in absolute value, then so does their product $fg$.
2. If $f$ and $g$ only have coefficients $0,1,$ or $-1$, then so does their product $fg$.

Now, we have the identity (3)

$$(X-1)H(X)=X^{2n-1}+X^{2n-2}+\cdots+X^n-X^{n-1}-X^{n-2}-\cdots-X-1$$
where
$$H(X)=X^{2n-2}+2X^{2n-1}+\cdots+(n-1)X^n+nX^{n-1}+(n-1)X^{n-2}+\cdots+2X+1$$

with coefficients increasing from $1$ to $n$ and then decreasing from $n-1$ to $1$. Define
$$P(x)=(x^p-1)H(x^q)$$

and $$Q(x)=(x^q-1)H(x^p)$$

$H(x^q)$ and $H(x^p)$ both have a coefficient equal to $n$ in absolute value, so $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ do too, from (1). And

$$P(x)Q(x)=(x^p-1)H(x^q)(x^q-1)H(x^p)=(x^p-1)H(x^p)(x^q-1)H(x^q)$$

From the identity (3), $(x^p-1)H(x^p)$ and $(x^q-1)H(x^q)$ are each polynomials with coefficients equal to $0,1,$ or $-1$. So, by (2), their product is too.

**Worked example**

Let $n=4, p=11,$ and $q=13$. Then

$$H(X)=X^6+2X^5+3X^4+4X^3+3X^2+2X+1$$
$$P(x)=(x^{11}-1)(x^{78}+2x^{65}+3x^{52}+4x^{39}+3x^{26}+2x^{13}+1)$$
$$=x^{89}-x^{78}+2 x^{76}-2 x^{65}+3 x^{63}-3 x^{52}+4 x^{50}-4 x^{39}+3 x^{37}-3 x^{26}+2 x^{24}-2 x^{13}+x^{11}-1$$
$$Q(x)=(x^{13}-1)(x^{66}+2x^{55}+3x^{44}+4x^{33}+3x^{22}+2x^{11}+1)$$
$$=x^{79}+2 x^{68}-x^{66}+3 x^{57}-2 x^{55}+4 x^{46}-3 x^{44}+3 x^{35}-4 x^{33}+2 x^{24}-3 x^{22}+x^{13}-2 x^{11}-1$$
$$P(x)Q(x)=x^{168}+x^{157}+x^{155}+x^{146}+x^{144}+x^{142}+x^{135}+x^{133}+x^{131}+x^{129}-x^{124}+x^{122}+x^{120}+x^{118}-x^{116}-x^{113}-x^{111}+x^{109}+x^{107}-x^{105}-x^{103}-x^{102}-x^{100}-x^{98}+x^{96}-x^{94}-x^{92}-x^{91}-x^{90}-x^{89}-x^{87}-x^{85}-x^{83}-x^{81}-x^{79}-x^{78}-x^{77}-x^{76}-x^{74}+x^{72}-x^{70}-x^{68}-x^{66}-x^{65}-x^{63}+x^{61}+x^{59}-x^{57}-x^{55}-x^{52}+x^{50}+x^{48}+x^{46}-x^{44}+x^{39}+x^{37}+x^{35}+x^{33}+x^{26}+x^{24}+x^{22}+x^{13}+x^{11}+1$$